# SVG Text not handling coordinates on style?

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to position SVG text by defining coordinates (`x` and `y`) in `style`, but it looks like that, differently from shapes like `<rect>`, setting `<text style="x: 100px; y: 100px">` has no effect, instead only `<text x=100px y=100px >` works. Is it even possible to set those coordinates by styling, like I used to do with other SVG elements? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [SVG 2](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-SVG2-20160915/text.html#TextElementXAttribute) the ‘text’ and ‘tspan’ ‘x’ and ‘y’ attributes are not presentation attributes and cannot be set via CSS. This may change in a future version of SVG.